# Pillow is not properly saving images (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have the following code:

```
out_image = Image.new('RGBA', (1024,600))
cur_color = (255,255,255,0)


for t in range(0, 100):
    out_image.putpixel((50,t),cur_color)
out_image.show()
out_image.save("test.png")
```

out_image.show() shows me the image with the pixels properly placed, however, test.png is saved as a blank image.

Comment: I don't know what is happening but can you share the details about `test.png`? Blank means black? Is it the right size? Is it a 32-bit image (4 channel)? Also, please provide a reproducible code sample so anyone can duplicate your issue without needing to setup their own data / code etc.

Comment: Yes, blank means black (the default background color). And the image appears to be the proper 1024*600 resolution. Code has been simplified. I have not done anything to specify how many bits the image is. So it is whatever is the default (I'm assuming 32)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `show()` is working because it first creates a temporary bitmap for display. The bitmap has no transparency so this points to your problem being related to transparency.

Use `255`:

```
cur_color = (255,255,255,255)  # instead of (255,255,255, 0)
```

Comment: The first suggestion yields an IOError, but the second suggestion works. Thanks!

Comment: @user3246167 Glad it works. Thanks for letting me know - I'll remove the one that fails.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `255, 255, 255, 1`?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the 255 means fully opaque/no transparency. So 1 would also work but it is only 1/255 away from fully transparent.